# how do you create these striped letters but especially the curves in it (see images)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, illustrator-effects

How does one create this effect? I know how you could create these lines, these might have been done with the blend tool or with a striped handmade brush. And the corners 90 degrees are possible with the brush tool or the blend.

But the corners 180 degrees are done so nicely, does anybody know how to create these in the easy way?

[image: whole artwork]

[image: closeup]

[image: closeup]

Artwork credits to: Ru.Rulo @instagram

Comment: Idont see any particularily hard problem here, callicraphic brushes and stroke width profiles should do this easily. Dont even consider the blend tool though.

Comment: Hi @joojaa thanks alot for your answer. Okay interesting the calligraphy brush tool, I can imagine that it could be easy but I don't see it yet how to do it, so I find it difficult to think how this could be achieved, could you happen to use a short description with screenshots here, please? Thanks alot for your help though.

Comment: If I would hazard a guess, I would say it might've been done just by multiple circles and lines: Circle with a stroke x5 + Straight lines with a stroke x5 for the swirly U turns. The closeups specifically might've been done exactly the same + `Object > Expand...` + clipping away extras with another circle. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR7N9.png (It might be even easier to expand the lines first and then drawing a circle with a fill instead of a stroke, like I did in this example)

Comment: @Joonas yeah the last picture detail seems to indicate this may have been the method.

Answer (score -1):

It’s done with the *Calligraphic Brush* tool and some stroke width!

Comment: Hi Rahman, welcome to GDSE and thanks for trying to help out. We are typically looking for longer answers though, that explain the _how_ and _why_ of a solution. Feel free to browse the site and take a look at some top-rated answers to see what gets upvotes. Then could  [edit] your answer and try to add more information? Thanks!